# Where is the list of "extended properties" to use in the PropertyFilters parameter of the Azure Devops Release Api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm building some tooling for my release pipelines using the Azure Devops sdk for making calls to the rest api.

I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters) that there is an option to filter properties.

> A comma-delimited list of extended properties to be retrieved. If set, the returned Release will contain values for the specified **property Ids** (if they exist). If not set, properties will not be included.

This seems to presuppose that the caller knows the ids (assuming property names?) by which to filter, but the documentation makes no allusions as to which properties are available. Since the KVP object is empty w/o valid property ids, and only contains values for those ids, this seems like a tribal knowledge problem.

Where is the list of properties to which this documentation is referring?

### Update

An example of an attempt at the answer given by **@Merlin Liang - MSFT**

```cs
using (var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(BasePath), _credentialsFactory.GetCredentials()))
            {
                var releaseClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient>();

                var releasesTask = releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(Project,
                                                                  releaseDefinitionId,
                                                                  expand: ReleaseExpands.Environments
                                                                          | ReleaseExpands.Approvals
                                                                          | ReleaseExpands.Artifacts, 
                                                                  propertyFilters: new []{"DeploymentStatus"});
                releasesTask.Wait();
                return releasesTask.Result;
            }
```

This request returns the following:
[image]

You can see that I am able to provide the flags for **?expand={PropertyExpands}** and I am getting those objects back, but the properties collection stays empty.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the list of properties to which this documentation is
>   referring?

Need to say that there are much description which very easily misleading users in the doc. In fact, **[Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#definitions)** is the properties mentioned to.

[image]

But, I am very afraid that users will be mislead by the name **propertyFilters**.

The things you need to watch out for is, **propertyFilters** does not mean filter based on release object properties. It just used for **expand** the result. In one word, it just specifies a list of extended properties which the user want it included in the results.

See this github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/182

Comment: I don't see this working the way you describe. I have edited my question to include the attempt at what is in your answer.